# How to debug an if statement that is not working?

Tags: java

```
import java.util.*;

public class ass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub 

        String[]c={"sid","is","cool"};
        List<String>list1=new ArrayList<String>();

        for(String w:c){
            list1.add(w);
        }
        String[]q={"is"};
        List<String>list2=new ArrayList<String>();
        for(String t:q){
            list2.add(t);
        }

        EditList(list1,list2);

        for(int i=0;i<list1.size();i++){
            System.out.printf("%s ", list1.get(i));
        }
    }

    public static void EditList(Collection<String>l1, Collection<String>l2){
        Iterator<String>it=l1.iterator();
        while(it.hasNext()){
            if(l2.contains(it.next()));
            it.remove();
        }
    }
}
```

In this programme I have two lists. I wanted to remove the items that are common in the first and second list from the first list and print it. I don't want a workaround or any other code suggestions. Can someone please explain why my code is not working?

I am following New Boston's tutorials.

Comment: Do you get any error message?

Comment: *"my code is not working"* - compiler error, runtime error, unexpected behaviour, not terminating - what is not working?

Comment: You have an extra `;` on the `l2.contains` line.

Comment: Follow @resueman comment.

Comment: Just for the record: in case you consider to keep the question and not delete it ... feel free to accept the answer best helping you.

Comment: Pro tip: when asking a technical question on the internet, put some thought and effort into your title. "Please help me", with or without begging, is not of use to anyone, and is likely to attract well-deserved downvotes. This is not Reddit or Facebook. Ditto for all-caps writing - there is really no need to shout.

Answer (score 5):

Here:

```
if(l2.contains(it.next()));
    it.remove();
```

That semicolon after **if** is a **real** statement.
Thus `it.remove()` happens always; like if ... that if not there!

Thus the real answer: always always always use

```
if (){ 
  stuff 
}
```

... even for single statements! Same for loops!

Comment: There was a time where typo questions were closed as what they are: typo questions ("This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error."). And this typo here is also a duplicate. But who would say "no" to 40 rep points, right? ;P

Comment: Sometimes I do. But sometimes you close out so many question a day, and watch people getting upvotes on them that you decide: this one guy over here ...

Comment: Or to be precise: most of the time I do the correct thing and vote to close. But then I have seen more 6-digits-reputation-semi-gods answer such questions than myself doing that. In that sense; I still consider myself being in good company.

Comment: If that's the company you like to be in, then that's your decision. Btw the dupe I was talking about: [Semicolon at end of 'if' statement](//stackoverflow.com/q/14112515)

Comment: I wasnt aware of that one. I will keep in mind, and promise to dup-close the next 5 ; questions to it!

Answer (score 1):

try

```
public static void EditList(Collection<String>l1, Collection<String>l2){
    Iterator<String>it=l1.iterator();
    while(it.hasNext()){
        String current=it.next();
        if(l2.contains(current)){
               i1.remove(current); // assuming u wish to remove from l1
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Using {} to enclose a conditional statement is always a foolproof strategy to avoid nasty results. Following is the best reconstruct -
`if(l2.contains(current)){
               i1.remove(current); // assuming u wish to remove from l1
}`